# how to call angularJS from another java script framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, sapui5

I am trying to connect angularJS with another Java script framework - UI5.
Scenario:
I have a custom angular tag in my UI5 application.
Change in UI5 must trigger the angularJS controller.

I am not getting how to keep the $apply/ $watch/ $broadcast outside of the controller/ directive and still communicate with rootScope.

I am looking for a basic code snippet to understand how to bridge two different java script frameworks.

Comment: Can you provide some relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for `rootScope`:

```
<div id="appContainer" ng-app="myApp">

angular.element('#appContainer').scope()
```

And this for an element's `scope` (in this case, the scope defined by `myController`:

```
<div id="cont1" ng-controller="myController">

angular.element('#cont1').scope()
```